# Unable to login first time to admin after installing Magento2

Tags: magento2

New installation of Magento2 on Ubuntu, the homepage and admin page loads, but doesn't accept the user/pass entered. There's no error message displayed either. Tried:

- different browsers, clearing cache & cookies
- timezone is correctly set on server.
- reset pass directly from database

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `localhost` as your hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`magento admin:user:create`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html#instgde-cli-admin) command to create a new administrator account or use the [`magento admin:user:unlock`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html#instgde-cli-admin-unlock) command to unlock the existing account.

Answer (score 0):

Change localhost to ip address(127.0.0.1) in your base url and secure base url in "core_config_data" table.

Or

check with your firefox browser without any change.